# find all jpg images from specific directory and copy it to other directory

Tags: linux, shell-script, command-line

How do I copy all the jpg images [files whose names end with .jpg] that exist in the directory `/usr/share/backgrounds` into to the jpg directory in `/week/pictures/final/jpg` then redirect any error messages that might appear to the file `cp.err` ?

```
cp *.jpg /usr/share/background /home/userName/week/pictures/final/jpg | ls 2>cp.err
```

I think this might be it. Can someone please clarify?

Answer (score 2):

Try:
`cp /usr/share/backgrounds/*.jpg /week/pictures/final/jpg/ 2> cp.err`

Note that the `cp.err` file will be created in the directory where you are when you run the command. If you want the error file in a differente directory, you can do:
`cp /usr/share/backgrounds/*.jpg /week/pictures/final/jpg/ 2> /desired_directory/cp.err`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `find` command :

```
find /usr/share/backgrounds -iname "*.jpg" -type f -exec /bin/cp {} /week/pictures/final/jpg 2>cp.err \;
```